# How do I modify serialized form data in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, serialization, fckeditor

I am trying to submit my form in AJAX, so I have to serialize() the data. But I am using `fckEditor` and jQuery doesn't know how to deal with it, so after the serialization, I am trying to manually modify the value, but no luck so far... any ideas

```
if(content_val!=""){
    var values = $("#frmblog").serialize();
    values.content = content_val; //content_val is the manually fetched data which I am trying to insert into the serialized content.
    alert(content_val); alert(values);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you insert it before serializing?

Comment: The problem is, there is some default values being set in the 'content' key during the serilization process, so I can't just attach a new value, I have to update the one already in it

Comment: Ah, that changes things; see my updated answer.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

[`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) returns a URL-encoded string containing the form fields. If you need to append to it, you do so using the standard URL-encoded string rules, e.g.:

```
var values = $("#frmblog").serialize();
values += "&content=" + encodeURIComponent(content_val);
```

(The above assumes there will always be one value in `values` after the `serialize` call; if that's not necessarily true, determine whether to use `&` based on whether `values` is empty before you add to it.)

Alternately, if you like, you can use [`serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) and then add to the array and use [`jQuery.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param) to turn the result into a query string, but that seems a long way 'round:

```
// You can also do this, but it seems a long way 'round
var values = $("#frmblog").serializeArray();
values.push({
    name: "content",
    value: content_val
});
values = jQuery.param(values);
```

---

**Update**: In a comment added later you said:

> The problem is, there is some default values being set in the 'content' key during the serilization process, so I can't just attach a new value, I have to update the one already in it"

That changes things. It's a pain to look for `content` within the URL-encoded string, so I'd go with the array:

```
var values, index;

// Get the parameters as an array
values = $("#frmblog").serializeArray();

// Find and replace `content` if there
for (index = 0; index < values.length; ++index) {
    if (values[index].name == "content") {
        values[index].value = content_val;
        break;
    }
}

// Add it if it wasn't there
if (index >= values.length) {
    values.push({
        name: "content",
        value: content_val
    });
}

// Convert to URL-encoded string
values = jQuery.param(values);
```

You'd probably want to make this a reusable function.

Answer (score 8):

With ES15 now.
You can use this instead one for editing current submitted value (the shortest one)

```
var values = $("#frmblog").serializeArray();
values.find(input => input.name == 'content').value = content_val;
console.log(values);
```

or native function

```
var values = $("#frmblog").serializeArray();
values.find(function(input) { 
    return input.name == 'content';
}).value = content_val;
console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a full jquery plugin based on @T.J's answer. You can call

```
$('form#myForm').awesomeFormSerializer({
    foo: 'bar',
})
```

Which will replace or add the param 'foo' with value 'bar' (or any other param you add in the object)

jQuery plugin :

```
// Not builtin http://stackoverflow.com/a/5075798/2832282
(function ( $ ) {
    // Pass an object of key/vals to override
    $.fn.awesomeFormSerializer = function(overrides) {
        // Get the parameters as an array
        var newParams = this.serializeArray();

        for(var key in overrides) {
            var newVal = overrides[key]
            // Find and replace `content` if there
            for (index = 0; index < newParams.length; ++index) {
                if (newParams[index].name == key) {
                    newParams[index].value = newVal;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Add it if it wasn't there
            if (index >= newParams.length) {
                newParams.push({
                    name: key,
                    value: newVal
                });
            }
        }

        // Convert to URL-encoded string
        return $.param(newParams);
    }
}( jQuery ));
```

Answer (score 1):

use the following function it worked for me

```
function(elementName,newVal)
{
    var postData = $("#formID").serialize();

var res = postData.split("&");
var str = "";

for(i=0;i<res.length;i++)
  {
    if(elementName == res[i].split("=")[0])
      {
        str += elementName + "=" + newVal+ "&";
      }
      else
      {
        str += res[i] + "&";
      }
  }
return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would accomplish what you need

```
formData = $('#'+formID).find(":input")
                            .filter(function (i, item) {
                                if (item.name.includes('nameToBeChanged'))
                                {
                                    item.name = item.name.replace('nameToBeChanged', 'toChangedName');
                                    return true;
                                } else {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }).serialize();
```

Do realize that this will change the form element names permanently