# Posting additional data alongside serialized form data

Tags: jquery

I want to post some additional data alongside serialized data i got from user form input.

For instance,

```
$.post('update.php', $("#theform").serialize(),{cposition:swidget}, function(data) {

});
```

This does not post the additional post.How am i supposed to post the additional data?.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I modify serialized form data in jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075778/how-do-i-modify-serialized-form-data-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery `serialize` function yields its values in the `&key=value` format. It does this using `$.param` internally. You would be able to append your own values in the same manner:

```
$.post('update.php', [$('#theform').serialize(), $.param({cposition:swidget})].join('&'), function(data) { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
var data = $('#theform').serializeArray();
data.push({cposition: swidget});
//then
$.post('update.php', data, function(data) {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can append something to the end of serialized string.

```
$.post('update.php', $("#theform").serialize() + '&cposition:swidget', function(data) {

});
```