# Is it possible to convert a string into HTTP POST variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

In the code below, I've used `.serialize()` to encode all of my form inputs as a string, which I then post to the server:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: wp_urls.ajax_url,
    data: {
        action: "submit_form",
        form: $("#myForm").serialize()
    }
});
```

I assumed the serialized form fields (stored in the `form` property of the `data` object) would become parameters of the query string. However, the only parameters being sent to the server are `action` and `form` with my serialized string being a value of the `form` field.

Is there a way to parse my serialized string into HTTP POST variables, before it hits the server or is there another way to handle the `$_POST["form"]` variable with server-side code?

Comment: `parse_str` on the server side.

Comment: How do you want to change a parameter before it hits the server? You can handle it either on the client (where you obviously serialize the form) or the server (where you could parse it). But between is nothing what you can do. It's out of your reach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to send a serialized query string of only the form data, you need to get rid of the `data` object literal, and only pass the serialized data:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: wp_urls.ajax_url,
    data: $("#myForm").serialize()
});
```

According to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (referring to `data`):

> It is converted to a query string, if not already a string.

This means that the object keys will be converted to parameters, and the values be will the corresponding parameter values.

If you want `submit_form` to exist as an `action` parameter, you can do this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: wp_urls.ajax_url,
    data: $("#myForm").serialize() + '&action=submit_form'
});
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5075798/2714730) regarding mutating jQuery form serialized data.

Why can you simply concatenate a string to the end of the serialized data? According to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation.

Comment: ...and adding a key-value pair to the form is as simple as temporarily adding a hidden field when serializing the form.

Comment: OP will probably need to append `action=submit_form` in there somewhere

Comment: @zzzzBov, correct, yes thanks for pointing that out. Updated the answer.

Comment: This is so simple I don't know how I didn't see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
data = new FormData($('#form_id).get(0)),
```

this form will collect data from the bind to object in key value pairs (* provide name attribute in html tags )

in ajax call set

```
$.ajax({
url:url,
data:data,
type:'post',
processData = false,
contentType: false,
processData: false
});
```

* processData and contentType will not be modified based on header provided

Comment: Please provide an explanation for your code to better help people who might not understand it as is.

Comment: SyntaxError: `processData = false,`

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you can build your own `data`:

```js
var data = {};
$("#myForm").serializeArray().forEach(function(e) {
  if (data[e.name] !== undefined) {
    if ($.isArray(data[e.name])) {
      data[e.name].push(e.value);
    } else {
      data[e.name] = [data[e.name], e.value];
    }
  } else {
    data[e.name] = e.value;
  }
});
data['action'] = 'submit_form';
// just to check:
console.log($.param(data));
```

```html
<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input name="name" value="Amadan">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="1" checked>1
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="2" checked>2
</form>
```

You can then use normally `data: data` in `$.ajax`. If you don't expect multiple values per parameter, you can simplify it to:

```js
var data = {};
$("#myForm").serializeArray().forEach(function(e) { data[e.name] = e.value; });
data['action'] = 'submit_form';
// just to check:
console.log($.param(data));
```

```html
<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input name="name" value="Amadan">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="1" checked>1
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

to unserialize data in php use `parse_str` 
From PHP.net manual

> Parses str as if it were the query string passed via a URL and sets variables in the current scope.
>   $str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
>   parse_str($str);
>   echo $first;  // value
>   echo $arr[0]; // foo bar
>   echo $arr[1]; // baz
>   parse_str($str, $output);
>   echo $output['first'];  // value
>   echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
>   echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz

```
parse_str($form, $inputs);

    foreach ($inputs as $key => $value) {

        $_POST[$key] = $value;
    }
```

give this shot.