# How to have input field outside form tags submit using serialized AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a form that submits five times using AJAX requests.  I have a value outside these form tags, **referer_fname**, which I would like to append to each AJAX request.  How can I achieve this?

Below is my script so far:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  <!--serial submit ajax-->
  <script>
     function mySubmit(){
     var myForms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
     for (var t = 0; t<myForms.length; t++){
     $.post("http://", $(myForms).eq(t).serialize(), function (data, status) {
      if (status === "success"){
     window.location.href= "http://redirect.com";
     }  
     }
     )
     }  
     }  

  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append to the serialized form fields output (see [this the accepted answer on this post for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5075798/1575353))

```
function mySubmit(){
  var myForms = $("form");
  myForms.each(function(index) {
    var form = myForms.eq(index);
    var serializedForm = form.serialize();
    serializedForm += '&referer_fname='+$('#refererFrame').val();
    $.post("https://", serializedForm, function (data, status) {
      if (status === "success"){
       window.location.href= "http://redirect.com";
      }  
    });   
  });
}
```