# AJAX not posting values with $(form).serialize()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a form that I'm trying to submit via AJAX. The easiest way for me to pass the data would be using `$("#myForm").serialize()`, however, when doing so, the page to which I'm posting to doesn't receive the data.

Here's my form:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input name="field" id="field">
    <button id="submitBtn" type="button">
</form>
```

And this is my function:

```
$("#submitBtn").click(function(){

    alert($("#myForm").serialize()) //For testing – does alert "field=value"

    var post = $.post("actions.php", $("#myForm").serialize());
    post.done(function(d){alert(d)}); //Only alerts [PHPSESSID]

    var post = $.post("actions.php", {field:"fieldVal"});
    post.done(function(d){alert(d)}); //Alerts [PHPSESSID] and ['field']

});
```

This is my whole `actions.php` file:

```
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);
exit();
```

Why is passing the values as JSON working but `.serialize()` isn't??

Comment: there is more than one argument to post.done()'s callback...

Comment: Also you need to have a value="" on your input http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075778/how-do-i-modify-serialized-form-data-in-jquery/5075798#5075798

Comment: @dandavis Yeah but I just need to prove if the values are being posted or not so I just need the first one

Comment: @mplungjan It's a text field. I type whatever value in. That's why I specified than when I alert the serialized form it looks perfectly fine

Comment: Try `<input type="text" name="field" id="field" value="" />`

Comment: `field=value != {"field":"value"}`; one is a string, one is an object, are the interchangeable in jq?

Comment: @mplungjan I set it to value="test" and it's still not posting it /:

Comment: @dandavis jQuery's $.post() can work with either. Or at least it's supposed to

Comment: Then there is a PHP issue

Comment: real ajax can simply `.send(elementForm)`, no need to serialize. not sure if jq's version can do the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just had to pass the serialized form as a variable instead of serializing it inside the `$.post()` function. As so:

```
var postData = $("#myForm").serialize()

var post = $.post("actions.php", postData);
post.done(function(d){alert(d)});
```

Not sure why it works when established outside and not inside the function, maybe a conflict issue. Thanks to everyone anyway

Comment: No reason that this should work any different than in the question

Answer (score -1):

Use `serializeArray()` instead: https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: He just needs a value on the field

Comment: Same thing happens /: