# Rails Ajax call 404 error for the edit view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a button on my new and edit views that sends a post request to my Letter controller through an Ajax call. If the Ajax call works perfectly in the new view, it throws a 404 error for my edit view.

Route:

```
  post 'letters/ajax_send_test_botletter', to: 'letters#send_test_botletter', as: 'send_test_botletter'
```

The form is defined like this:

```
<%= form_for(letter, :html => {class: "directUpload", remote: true}) do |f| %>
```

The button triggering the Ajax call in the form:

```
<button class="cta3" id="send_test_letter">Send a test campaign to yourself</button>
```

Ajax call:

```
  $('#send_test_letter').on('click', function(){
    $('form').submit(function() {
      var valuesToSubmit = $(this).serialize();
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/letters/ajax_send_test_botletter",
          data: valuesToSubmit,
          dataType: "JSON" // you want a difference between normal and ajax-calls, and json is standard
      }).success(function(json){
          if(json['value'] == "No Recipient") {
            $('#send_test_letter').css('display', 'none');
            $('#save_test_user').css('display', 'block');
          } else {
            console.log("Success")
            $('#confirmation_test_sent').html('Test successfully sent. Check your Messenger.')
          }
          $('form').unbind('submit');
      });
      return false; // prevents normal behaviour
    });
  });
```

My send_test_botletter method

```
def send_test_botletter

    @message_content = params[:letter]['messages_attributes']['0']['content']

    @button_message = params[:letter]['messages_attributes']['0']['buttons_attributes']['0']['button_text'] if params[:letter]['messages_attributes']['0']['buttons_attributes']['0']['button_text'] != ''
    @button_url = params[:letter]['messages_attributes']['0']['buttons_attributes']['0']['button_url'] if params[:letter]['messages_attributes']['0']['buttons_attributes']['0']['button_url'] != ''
    @cards = params[:letter]['cards_attributes'] if params[:letter]['cards_attributes'].present? == true

    @test_segment = Segment.where(core_bot_id: @core_bot_active.id, name: "test").first
    @recipients = BotUser.where(core_bot_id: @core_bot_active.id, source: @test_segment.token)

    if @recipients.exists?
      send_message_onboarding if @message_content != '' and @button_message.present? == false
      send_message_button_onboarding if @message_content != '' and @button_message.present? == true and @button_url.present? == true
      send_card_onboarding if @cards

      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: {"value" => "Success"}}
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: {"value" => "No Recipient"}}
      end
    end
  end
```

I get the following error in the Chrome console for the edit view:

> POST http://localhost:3000/letters/ajax_send_test_botletter 404 (Not
>   Found)

And in my Rails logs:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Letter with
>   'id'=ajax_send_test_botletter):

It seems it calls the Update method instead of the send_test_botletter method...

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: Can u post also `letters#send_test_botletter` method.

Comment: I just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the trick. The problem was the PATCH method in the edit form.

I found a plugin in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075778/how-do-i-modify-serialized-form-data-in-jquery/49322459#49322459) in order to modify the serialized data and change the method to "post":

```
$('#send_test_letter').on('click', function(){
    $('form').submit(function() {
      var valuesToSubmit = $(this).awesomeFormSerializer({
          _method: 'post',
      });
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/letters/ajax_send_test_botletter",
          data: valuesToSubmit,
          dataType: "JSON" // you want a difference between normal and ajax-calls, and json is standard
      }).success(function(json){
          if(json['value'] == "No Recipient") {
            $('#send_test_letter').css('display', 'none');
            $('#save_test_user').css('display', 'block');
          } else {
            console.log("Success")
            $('#confirmation_test_sent').html('Test successfully sent. Check your Messenger.')
          }
          $('form').unbind('submit');
      });
      return false; // prevents normal behaviour
    });
  });

(function ( $ ) {
    // Pass an object of key/vals to override
    $.fn.awesomeFormSerializer = function(overrides) {
        // Get the parameters as an array
        var newParams = this.serializeArray();

        for(var key in overrides) {
            var newVal = overrides[key]
            // Find and replace `content` if there
            for (index = 0; index < newParams.length; ++index) {
                if (newParams[index].name == key) {
                    newParams[index].value = newVal;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Add it if it wasn't there
            if (index >= newParams.length) {
                newParams.push({
                    name: key,
                    value: newVal
                });
            }
        }

        // Convert to URL-encoded string
        return $.param(newParams);
    }
}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: is there a simpler way these days in Rail 6 to fix this issue without using the plugin you referred to?

Answer (score 0):

`form_for(letter...` generates a different url and method depending whether or not the instance is persisted, defaulting to `create` and `post` or `update` and `patch` as appropriate.

When you hit submit, it's trying to hit this endpoint, *before* your listener kicks in. And in doing so, breaks the remaining js.

However, you can also provide `url` and `method` options to `form_for`. Try providing a blank `url` option and the correct method (`form_for letter, ..., url: '', method: :post`).

Alternatively, you could stop the default behaviour / propagation on form submission:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) { 
  e.stopPropagation() // Or could simply be `preventDefault()`, depending on your use case
  ...
  // your AJAX
}
```

Able to test out these approaches?

---

**Update**

Your method is actually nesting a `submit` listener within the `click` one. Try the following:

```
  $('#send_test_letter').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
    var $form = $(this).closest('form')
    var valuesToSubmit = $form.serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/letters/ajax_send_test_botletter",
        data: valuesToSubmit,
        dataType: "JSON" // you want a difference between normal and ajax-calls, and json is standard
    }).success(function(json){
        if(json['value'] == "No Recipient") {
          $('#send_test_letter').css('display', 'none');
          $('#save_test_user').css('display', 'block');
        } else {
          console.log("Success")
          $('#confirmation_test_sent').html('Test successfully sent. Check your Messenger.')
        }
      return false; // prevents normal behaviour
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, none of this worked. However, if I specify method: :post in the form definition, the Ajax call works (but the normal submit button doesn't). I guess it's a problem with the method, in the new view it's a post form, in the edit view it's PATCH.

Comment: Ah yes, that'll be it. As with the path changes in my first paragraph, the method changes too. Let me update the answer. And I've actually just spotted something else. Check me answer in two mins :)

Comment: Thanks for your edits. Unfortunately, now the Ajax button works but not the one to regularly submit the form. I get this error in Chrome console: POST http://localhost:3000/letters/63/edit 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Was actually just writing a further update, in there now. I think this should do it - just be sure `var $form = $(this).closest('form')` actually finds the form. Does that work?

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the error: POST http://localhost:3000/letters/ajax_send_test_botletter 404 (Not Found)

Comment: In valuesToSubmit, the method is patch, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I found the solution, just posted it. Thanks for your help!